# How to resize icons using the svg framework

Tags: font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I got Font Awesome 5 to work using:

```
<i class="fa fa-user"></i>
<script src="/js/packs/solid.js"></script>
<script src="/js/fontawesome.js"></script>
```

But styling the i tag didn't have any effect. So I tried using a web-font instead:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome-core.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome-solid.css">
<i class="fas fa-user"></i>
```

and it worked. But shouldn't I be using the svg framework? I'm not a Font Awesome traditionalist. Can you style fonts with different colors, sizes and rotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FontAwesome5 SVG framework converts the  tag into the fully rendered SVG code in the source.

The styling of the icon/SVG can be controlled by styling the parent.

```
<div style="font-size: 200%; color: red">
<i class="fas fa-user"></i>
</div>
```

This will render the icon at 2x size and in red.